# MongDB sink connector: How to use a field from json as _id

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm trying to ingest json data from Kafka topic to MongoDB using MongoDB-Kafka-Connect and have the following properties configured

```
topics=example
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=example
collection=example

document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing=false
writemodel.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy
document.id.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder,com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy
document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list=id
document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type=AllowList


errors.tolerance=all
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name=error_queue
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
```

For example, consider the below json

```
{
 "payload_id": 10,
 "meta_info": "some deep object",
 "info": {
   "id": "5",
   "name":"john",
   "email":"john@john.com"
  }
}
```

I want to ingest this data into MongoDB and use `info.id` as _id field inside the collection.

Also be able to upsert the document based on `info.id` field

```
{
 "payload_id": 10,
 "meta_info": "some deep object",
 "info": {
   "id": "5",
   "name":"john",
   "email":"john@johnmax.com",
  }
}
```

and the `email` should be updated based on `info.id` field in the collection

Comment: I would feel the better option is Simple Message Transformations.
Check ExtractField SMT from confluent or write your own.
Hope this will help you.